# How to give an ordinary user privileged access to a particular syscall in FreeBSD?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I want to give an ordinary user the ability to fchown() files arbitrarily (as if they were the superuser) on FreeBSD. Generally speaking, is there a right way to change the privilege-checking of a given syscall?

I investigated Capsicum, but for all the articles on the topic, there is a real lack of practical examples out there.

Comment: why not use `sudo`?

Comment: @mindthemonkey I don't want to fork an external program; I want to change the rules of the syscall itself.

Comment: @ruief: Then I think the answer is clear: edit the source code.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create your own program that calls `fchown()`, chown it to root:wheel and set the setuid bit (`chmod +s`), files run with the setuid bit will be run as the owner the the executable.

**Warning**
You didn't give any specific context, but be aware that allowing a user to run `fchown()` as root is a foot in the door to gain access to the entire system. For example, one might change the owner of `/etc/{passwd,group,shadow}`, change the contents, change the owner back, and presto! Instant root.

Comment: I don't want to fork an external program; I want to change the rules of the syscall itself. I am aware of the security implications of doing so.